# How do I multiply each element in the list by a given number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

I want to multiply each element in a list by a given number.

For example, when I key in the following on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\bella\projects\testing1> test.py 5,10,15,20,25,30 2
```

The result should be: `[10,20,30,40,50,60]`
(Note: each element is multiplied by 2)

or

```
C:\Users\bella\projects\testing1> test.py 5,10,15,20,25,30 0.5
```

The result should be: `[2.5,5,7.5,10,12.5,15]`
(Note: each element is multiplied by 0.5)

Here is my code...

```
import sys

user_input = sys.argv[1]
u_split = user_input.split(",")
option = sys.argv[2]

n = map(lambda x:x*(option), user_input)
print(n)
```

This is what I get on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\bella\projects\testing1> test.py 10,20,30,40,50,60 2
<map object at 0x03588160>
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda x:x*(option), user_input))`

Comment: `map` returns a list in Python2 but returns an iterator un Python3. You need to cast it in list

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your input into numbers first. And then, `map` is lazy - you'll need a `list()` to turn the map into a list.

```
import sys

user_input = sys.argv[1]
u_split = user_input.split(",")
option = float(sys.argv[2]) # parse into float

n = list(map(lambda x: float(x)*option, u_split))
print(n)
```

Or simply:

```
n = [float(x) * option for x in u_split]
```